# How to find source data of file in FAT32 by clusters and FAT table?

Tags: filesystems, fat32

I have some FAT32 structure output:

```
bytes_per_sector        0x200
sectors_per_cluster     0x8
reserved_sector_count   0x780
FATtable_count          0x2
root_entry_count        0
hidden_sector_count     0x38
total_sectors_32        0xf17fc8
FATtable_size_32        0x3c40
root_cluster            0x2
fat_info                0x1
backup_BS_sector        0x6
```

Ok, assume to this information, I jump over `reserved_sector_count` and get the FAT32 table. #1920 - is offset from te begining - 0x780.

```
fat32Table #1920 
        cluster0     ffffff8
        cluster1     ffffffff
        cluster2     fffffff
        cluster3     fffffff
```

Ok, assume to `FATtable_size_32` and `FATtable_count` I jump over and get to the Data Region at the position #16777216 from the begining. This is the 0 cluster, as I understand. Cluster consists of 8 sectors by 512 byte each. First Directory named "F" - is volume. Second "HELLO.TXT" is a file. DirectoryEntry size of 32 byte.

```
name #16777216       46 [F       ]
ext                  [   ]
attrib                8
NTreserved            0
CrtTimeTenth          0
createtime            0
createdate            0
accessdate            0
clusterhigh           0
modifiedtime          81e3
modifieddate          4ace
clusterlow            0
filesize              0

name #16777216       48 [HELLO   ]
ext                  [TXT]
attrib                20
NTreserved            18
CrtTimeTenth          5c
createtime            82ca
createdate            4ace
accessdate            4ace
clusterhigh           0
modifiedtime          82d4
modifieddate          4ace
clusterlow            3
filesize              24
```

Next, I want to find data according to "hello.txt" file. I see `clusterlow`= 0x03. When I jump to next cluster (+4096 byte) and see data of my file.

```
name #16781312       This is test
```

But I don't get how does `clusterlow` help me to find it? What clusters ffffff8, ffffffff, fffffff in FAT32 table? How to find source data according to all this stuff?

Comment: http://elm-chan.org/docs/fat_e.html This will help you with definitions what it means when cluster is bad, empty, used, etc.

Comment: This is a question aabout data structures. It is clearly not related to the C language. And we are not an explanation site for data structures. Information about FAT are available by a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

@tilz0R, thanks for a link, but I have already read a doc from MS. And more.

I just get that at the DataRegion (after reserved sectors and FAT32 table) we begin with the cluster2, and clusterlow=0x03 means that source data located in the next cluster3 which is +4096 byte lower than cluster2.

It was easier to understand when I add one more file on a disk and see that first file located in the cluster3 and the second - cluster4.